# How do I add the Databricks spark-csv package to a Python Jupyter notebook on IBM Bluemix

Tags: python, apache-spark, ibm-cloud, pyspark

I know I should add it as a package requirement when launching pyspark:

```
$SPARK_HOME/bin/spark-shell --packages com.databricks:spark-csv_2.11:1.4.0
```

But in Bluemix, spark is already running and a spark context is already defined.  How can I add this package?

On a side note, would I be able to do this in Scala?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently on Bluemix, using `PySpark`in a Python notebook, it is not possible to add `spark-csv` to the environment.

However, you can add it in a Scala notebook using this command:

```
%AddDeps com.databricks spark-csv_2.10 1.3.0 --transitive
```

Of course, you may choose another version of the package.

For Scala notebooks and the corresponding Spark kernel have a look at the following documentation:
https://github.com/ibm-et/spark-kernel/wiki/List-of-Current-Magics-for-the-Spark-Kernel